# Creating Jenkins jobs to accent paramater before running

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins to run a bunch of my scripts on regular basis. And the Execute shell section of my job looks like:

```
runner.py my_script A.config run
```

The problem is I have a bunch of configs A.config, B.config .... S.config. I am currently creating separate jobs for each config. And have a bunch of jobs. Is there any plugin you would recommend so that I can just have "runner.py my_script" and pass in A.config or B.config... using a simpler option than having a bunch of job like I have right now?

Answer (score 0):

You can a achieve this with the multi configuration job in Jenkins. Select it as the radio button entry when naming the job

Here is more information [Jenkins and multi-configuration (matrix) jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515730/jenkins-and-multi-configuration-matrix-jobs)

It is a standard Jenkins feature so doesn't need a plugin and you can add your own labels in.