# can i schedule two gradle tasks with jenkins matrix configuration?

Tags: java, jenkins

I want to run several gradle tasks seperatly on the same gradle project.

With different scheduling for example: one task to create a baseline, and one task for periodic analysis of the baseline.

I saw these posts:

[post1](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Combinations+Plugin)

[post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515730/jenkins-and-multi-configuration-matrix-jobs)

Does jenkins matrix configuration can help me with that?

I see it's mainly to run on a different JDK and different OS,

or I can actually define `config1` with `gradle_task1` that will be run

and then only when I choose to run of `config2` with `gradle_task2` on the same project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is have a 'TextAxis' as your axis type and give it values of the gradle tasks. I think this comes as standard

[image: task definition]

Then in the [gradle plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin)

use ${task} as the task you want to run

[image: gradle plugin]

I think you could then pick the task you want based on the [matrix combination plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Combinations+Plugin) as you mentioned.

If you want tasks to run concurrently then you need to check the 'execute concurrent build' box on the matrix job