# Jenkins CI: How to trigger jenkins jobs based on different Xcode project configurations

Tags: ios, objective-c, jenkins, xcode6, jenkins-plugins

I am able to trigger jenkins job whenever i commit my ios project in SVN.
But my project has 4-5 configuration e.g. Debug, Release, DebugStaging, ReleaseStaging, DebugLive.
So what i want to achieve is, whenever I commit in SVN, jenkins should build 4-5 jobs based on my xcode configuration.

I tried in Jenkins Item configuration under `Build -> Xcode -> General Build Settings -> Configuration` to write DebugStaging, but it fails my jenkins job.

Answer (score 1):

With the [Xcode plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin), you have an option to set the configuration you want to use:

> **configuration**: This is the name of the configuration as defined in the Xcode project.
>   By default there are Debug and Release configurations.

---

Then you will probably want to create a **multi-configuration** (matrix) Project.

> The Configuration Matrix allows you to specify what steps to
>   duplicate, and create a multiple-axis graph of the type of builds to
>   create.

Basically in your job configuration page:

- in *Configuration Matrix*, add a "User-defined axis" with name `CONFIGURATION` and values `Debug, Release, DebugStaging, ReleaseStaging, DebugLive`.
- in *Build*, add a "Conditional step" (single or multiple):

  - in *Run?*, select "always",
  - in *Builder*, select your Xcode builder and set its `CONFIGURATION` to :

    ```
     ${ENV, var="CONFIGURATION"}
    ```

Your job should finally run as many times as you have configurations, that is 5 times.

---

*Additional reading:*

- [Building a matrix project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project)
- [How to configure jenkins multi-configuration build and test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554173/how-to-configure-jenkins-multi-configuration-build-and-test)
- [Jenkins and multi-configuration (matrix) jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515730/jenkins-and-multi-configuration-matrix-jobs)

Comment: HI, Thanks alot,
 your answer seems relevant but i am still confused, what do you mean by "in Build, add a "Conditional step" (single or multiple)" i dont know how to do this.

Comment: I upvoted your answer bcoz its really useful, but still i am stuck in the way i want. I will try ur solution also.
Thanks alot

Comment: I am talking about "parts" of your job configuration page. It is divided into categories, such as "Advanced Project Options", "Build Triggers", "Configuration Matrix", etc. and this where you can add actions.